# GNURadio peak coordinates detection

Tags: plot, signal-processing, gnu, gnuradio

i have a power vs frequency plot on GNURadio software and i need to detect the value of the highest power peak and then get its corresponding frequency value. can anybody suggest a method to do that?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbIbh.png]

Comment: first of all, those are damn little digital numbers, very close to the numerical accuracy of single-point floating point numbers. then, it's ill-adviced to use WX GUI for new GNU Radio applications. We're definitely releasing the next version of GNU Radio soon, and that will only contain Qt and no WX anymore. We've been spreading that announcement for three years, at least. Then: What you want is not to detect the peak of a graphical line, but the frequency of a signal, right? (just like you would want to swat a mosquito, not "hit the position where the humming noise comes from")

Comment: How and where do you want to do this? Inside GNU Radio? Inside a script? Otherwise, the most naive approach would be to use a script finding the max within the signal and link this value to the frequency, but I guess this is not 'exactly' what you want. Could you clarify?

Comment: i tried finding the frequency using GNURadio blocks but couldn't get any results, so if you know any method to do that using the already found blocks then it would be great. my second option was writing a python script and adding my own block. the output of the complex to mag^2 block will act as an input to the customized block. can you help me with that ?

Comment: and the script you described about finding the max and linking it to the frequency is exactly what i want to do. if you can help me with that i will be thankful

Comment: Can you get a file containing the trace of your signal? If yes, please provide a link to the file so I can see what I can come up as a solution.

Comment: can you help me obtain the trace file please? i am still a newbie in ubuntu and gnuradio.